# How to add edited tasks in Todo app to Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to add edited task to local storage. I don't know how to replace an element in the array with new element.

[image]

I have tried to iterate through an array and if an element in the array is not equal to value of input(task) it will delete by the splice method and push a new element, but the problem is that push method adds an element to the end of the array.

```js
function editToLocal(todo) {
    let todos;
    if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
        todos = [];
    }
    else {
        todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
    }

    const todoIndex = todo.indexOf(todo.value);
    const todosIndex = todos.index0f(todoIndex);

    todos.forEach((item) => {
        if (item !== todo) {
            todos.splice(todosIndex, 1);
            todos.push(todo);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the splice method allows you to also add one or more elements to the array.

So for example you can do:

```js
let todos = ['job 1', 'job 2', 'job 3', 'job 4'];

console.log(todos);

todos.splice(1, 1, 'job a');

console.log(todos);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with:

```js
let tasks = ["task1", "task2", "task3"];

const taskToReplaceIndex = tasks.indexOf("theTaskToBeReplaced")

tasks = tasks.map((task, index) => {
  if(index === taskToReplaceIndex) return "someNewTask"
  return task
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).